# Why does my httpurlconnection throw a 500 error?

Tags: java, html, httpurlconnection, xenforo

I'm trying to get my game server to link up with my Xenforo forums but it pulls a 500 error when trying to connect.
Its definitely reading the databases as i can type an incorrect username when logging in and it will tell me to register. But if i use a username that exists it throws the error.

This is the error in my Central server console :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost//extra/xenforo/index.php
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at io.ruin.api.utils.PostWorker.post(PostWorker.java:65)
at io.ruin.api.utils.PostWorker.postArray(PostWorker.java:82)
at io.ruin.api.utils.XenPost.post(XenPost.java:14)
at io.ruin.central.model.world.WorldLogin.lambda$new$0(WorldLogin.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I've tried messing with the post string but can't get it to connect keeps catching IOException E

```js
public class PostWorker {

    public static String post(String url, Map<Object, Object> postMap) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");

            try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                boolean first = true;
                for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> post : postMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = URLEncoder.encode(""+post.getKey(), "UTF-8");
                    String value = URLEncoder.encode(""+post.getValue(), "UTF-8");
                    ps.print((first ? "" : "&") + key + "=" + value);
                    first = false;
                }
            }

            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    response.append(line);
                return response.toString();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(con != null)
                con.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public static String post(String url, byte[] data) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length));

            try(DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    response.append(line);
                return response.toString();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(con != null)
                con.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public static String postArray(String url, Map<Object, Object> map) {
        return post(url, JsonUtils.toJson(map).getBytes());
    }

}
```

Above is the java code which uses the HTTPurlconnection.

```html
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2020:19:06:22 -0400] "POST /extra/xenforo/index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 1794 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Above is what the apache access.log posts.

My friend hosts the same server same files and has no problem connecting.
I'd also like to note i'm using Xampp to host the forum files not sure if that effects anything.

Thanks if anybody can help :)

Comment: `500` is "internal server error" - meaning there was an error in the server code. Check the server logs for errors and edit the question to include the relevant code

Comment: @Joni Thanks for the reply, Doesn't seem to be any anything related logged in the server logs. I checked both the central server and the Game server logs and the Nothing gets posted when i try to login. Been trying stuff for like 3 days, Tried different Xampp versions, different php versions. The server code is the exact same as my friends yet it doesn't throw him the connection error :/

Comment: Maybe not related, but the address has a double backslash after localhost, and does not seem like a valid address/link: `http://localhost//extra/xenforo/index.php`

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks for pointing that out but tried with just one backslash and same error bud. Also tried with 127.0.0.1 and my actual domain in replace of localhost but no luck

Comment: Did you check both Apache logs and application logs? Another approach is to remove things from the PHP script until it starts working. Or sending the request to a "hello world" PHP script and gradually add more things.

Comment: @Joni I posted what the apache access.log posts in my post, The application logs doesn't post anything unfortunately. What do u mean by remove things from the PHP script? As in the PHP folder on my apache? As when i tried different versions they had different files in them? or do you mean the page that the error is pointing to? As that link only has an authorization key inside it really which matches with the server side version.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Access log only tells you the request was made and returned an error. As for removing things from the PHP script, I mean doing a *binary search* for the cause of the error, if you comment out half of the script and find it works that means the error is in the commented part. It's less effective than finding an error message in the logs but sometimes necessary

Comment: Nothing in the error log nope, I've tried removing things from the code and  also compared the code to others and people have the same code as me and it works for them. I bought all the website and game server code and they work for my friend but not for me. He helped me set it up in the same way but mine throws the 500 error.

Comment: I think i may have found a possible solution, Inside where the error is pointing to links to more files which link to a page called XF.php which finds the data from the databases. This page is throwing the error 'Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.' Which when i look up looks to apache server errors. I've tried setting require local to global like it says but no luck. Doesn't even let me when i try on local.

Comment: Theres also a .htaccess file next to the XF.PHP file which has Order allow,deny
Deny from all in the code and i switched it round but still doesn't work

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for log file configurations and server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.